# Scala Spire: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spire.algebra.EuclideanRing[T] x % 12 ^

Tags: scala, generics, spire

I am not really sure what's going on here. I wanted to implement a few algorithms that I would like to operate on Ints and Floats. This led me to try out Spire. Here is the simplest example of the compile error I am facing.

```
import spire.algebra._  
import spire.math._      
import spire.implicits._ 

def mod12[T: Numeric](x: T): T = {
  x % 12
}
```

> Error:(17, 4) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
>   type spire.algebra.EuclideanRing[T]   x % 12   ^

Comment: You may want to `import spire.implicits._`

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned it is imported.

Comment: Shouldn't it be mod12[T: EuclidianRing]? % is available (mod) on EuclidianRing.

Comment: On second thought, EuclidianRing would only allow modulo between two T, not a T and an Int. There is no modulo in Numeric (not clear which algebraic structure it is, at least ring, possibly field, and ordered too). Dependencing on what you are trying to achieve, you might need your own type class.

Comment: So in other words, Numeric is too broad and there may or may not be a % depending on whatever T is?

Comment: I am trying to define a few types for dealing with simple modular arithmetic. Modulo 256 and Modulo 2PI specifically for operating on color hues and rotations. Maybe spire is overkill for my purposes and defining my own type class is the way to go but I wanted to try it out. ~6 hours of research to avoid duplicating ~6 lines of code :) That's what learning Scala will do to you I guess.